# why Visjs network is reappearing when i try to update any node

Tags: angular, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am trying to update the hidden attribute of visjs network's node.
by clicking the node, the node should be invisible without disturbing the graph.
can anyone help me with this I am new.
code I am trying -

```
this.network.on('click', function (properties) {
      var ids = properties.nodes;
      if(ids.length==0)
        return
   
      treeData.nodes.update({id:ids,hidden:true}) //treeData is object containing two dataSets (nodes and edges);
      
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The object generated by the click event contains an array of IDs rather than a single ID. The definition of this can be seen at https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#Events.

At present the code is passing this array in as a single id `treeData.nodes.update({id:ids,hidden:true})` which generates an error `"Error: Node must have an id"`. Instead of this it should loop through the array of IDs updating each.

```js
network.on('click', function (properties) {
  var ids = properties.nodes;

  // ids is an array, update each item
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
    treeData.nodes.update({id:ids[i],hidden:true})
    }      
});
```

Example can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/3yshgam1/ and also incorporated into this post below.

```js
// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
  { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
  { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
  { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
  { id: 5, label: "Node 5" },
]);

// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([
  { from: 1, to: 3 },
  { from: 1, to: 2 },
  { from: 2, to: 4 },
  { from: 2, to: 5 },
  { from: 3, to: 3 },
]);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
var treeData = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges,
};
var options = {};
var network = new vis.Network(container, treeData, options);

network.on('click', function (properties) {
  var ids = properties.nodes;

  // ids is an array, loop through the items
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
    treeData.nodes.update({id:ids[i],hidden:true})
  }      
});
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  width: 600px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
```

Full example: